# Map a PostGIS geometry point field with Hibernate on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot, postgis

In my PostgreSQL 9.3 + PostGIS 2.1.5 I have a table `PLACE` with a column `coordinates` of type `Geometry(Point,26910)`.

I want to map it to `Place` entity in my Spring Boot 1.1.9 web application, which uses Hibernate 4.0.0 + . `Place` is available with a REST repository.

Unfortunately when I `GET http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/places` I receive **this strange JSON response**:

```
{

  "_embedded" : {

    "venues" : [ {

      "id" : 1,

      "coordinates" : {

        "envelope" : {

          "envelope" : {

            "envelope" : {

              "envelope" : {

                "envelope" : {

                  "envelope" : {

                    "envelope" : {

                      "envelope" : {

                        "envelope" : {

                          "envelope" : {

                            "envelope" : {

                              "envelope" : {

                                "envelope" : {

                                  "envelope" : {

                                    "envelope" : {

                                      "envelope" : {

                                        "envelope" : {

                                          "envelope" : {

                                            "envelope" : {
```

and so on indefinetely...! Spring log doesn't help..

I'm working with this application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.123/mywebapp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=mypwd
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

First of all, is it ok to use `database-platform` instead of `database`?
And maybe do I have to use following settings instead of the above?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://192.168.1.123/mywebapp
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgis.DriverWrapper
```

Anyway my entity is something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Place {
    @Id
    public int id;
    @Column(columnDefinition="Geometry")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")    //"org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType" seems to be for older versions of Hibernate Spatial
    public com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point coordinates;
}
```

My pom.xml contains this relevant part:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version><!-- compatible with Hibernate 4.3.x -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

A bit strange configuration, I found it on the internet, it is the one that works best for now.

I hope that someone could help me with this mistery. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally I discovered that my configuration is ok and might be **Jackson** that cannot manage `Point` data type correctly. So I customized its JSON serialization and deserialization:

- add these annotations to our `coordinates` field:

  ```
  @JsonSerialize(using = PointToJsonSerializer.class)
  @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonToPointDeserializer.class)
  ```
- create such serializer:

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
  import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

  public class PointToJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Point> {

      @Override
      public void serialize(Point value, JsonGenerator jgen,
              SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
              JsonProcessingException {

          String jsonValue = "null";
          try
          {
              if(value != null) {             
                  double lat = value.getY();
                  double lon = value.getX();
                  jsonValue = String.format("POINT (%s %s)", lat, lon);
              }
          }
          catch(Exception e) {}

          jgen.writeString(jsonValue);
      }

  }
  ```
- create such deserializer:

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
  import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
  import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
  import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
  import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.PrecisionModel;

  public class JsonToPointDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Point> {

      private final static GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 26910); 

      @Override
      public Point deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
              throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

          try {
              String text = jp.getText();
              if(text == null || text.length() <= 0)
                  return null;

              String[] coordinates = text.replaceFirst("POINT ?\\(", "").replaceFirst("\\)", "").split(" ");
              double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
              double lon = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

              Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(lat, lon));
              return point;
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              return null;
          }
      }

  }
  ```

Maybe you can also use [this serializer](http://www.boyunjian.com/javasrc/com.scaleset/scaleset-geo/0.9.0/_/com/scaleset/geo/geojson/GeometrySerializer.java) and [this deserializer](http://www.boyunjian.com/javasrc/com.scaleset/scaleset-geo/0.9.0/_/com/scaleset/geo/geojson/GeometryDeserializer.java), available [here](http://www.boyunjian.com/do/jarse/gadetail.do?group=com.scaleset&artifact=scaleset-geo&keyword=scaleset-geo).

Comment: I do notice that the output latitude and longitude from your Serializer are swapped. is that expected? 

This code explains it `double lat = value.getY();` and `double lon = value.getX();` 

thanks

Comment: @randytan I used this code long time ago, but I remember that latitude and longitude where in the right order. Where do you see them swapped?

Comment: If you send `POINT(A B)` and do `sys.out` to your variable `jsonValue = String.format("POINT (%s %s)", lat, lon);` you can see it's actually written to `POINT(B A)`. I just swap the code `value.getY()` and `value.getX()` to correct the position. Thanks

Comment: @bluish I wonder How can I make this as a POLYGON serializer and deserializer.

Answer (score 7):

The solutions above helped me to fix the problem. I simplify it so other people can understand.

I included this library in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.bedatadriven</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the POJO object I used. Then I was able to get the REST call to work without the envelope error and proper coordinates.

```
import com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.serialization.GeometryDeserializer;
import com.bedatadriven.jackson.datatype.jts.serialization.GeometrySerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

@Entity
@Table(name = "boundary")
public class Boundary {

    private int id;
    private Geometry geometry;

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return ogc_fid;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "geometry", columnDefinition = "Geometry")
    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }
}
```

My table had these 2 columns:

```
id       | integer            
geometry | geometry(Geometry,4326) |
```

Comment: saved my day :)

Comment: @Martin Naughton If I use  `@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDeserialize.class)`, it returns this error. ```incompatible types found java.lang.class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.jsondeserialize required: java.lang.Class<? extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer<?>>``` how can I use deserializer?

Answer (score 4):

With Hibernate 5.4 and Posgis 13+ its became very easy. We can just add latest hibernate-spatial dependency

```
    <!-- Hibernate Spatial for storing and retrieving geometries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Use [latest Posgis dialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/postgis/package-summary.html). Add in application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect
```

Then we can simply use JST geometry because its supported by Hibernate (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-types)).

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;

@Entity(name = "address")
public class Address {
 private Point location;
}
```

**SQL to create entity table :**

```
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS address (location geometry);
```

Further JTS GeoJSON Reader and Writer can be used to translate geometries into JSON (see [here](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/io/common/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/io/geojson/GeoJsonReader.java))

Comment: Helped a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This serialization/deserialization also worked fine for me.

https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't appear to be related to PostgreSQL.  It appears that your POJO has a backreference, which means that your mapper doesn't know how to handle it.  You need to explicitly define the recursive relationships so that the mapper knows when to stop. (My Goto link --> http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2010/10/json-jackson-to-rescue.html)

Comment: Having no reference to any other entity, this is not the issue. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the annotation on all your fields that are using a Point, you can also use the **@JsonComponent** to register your **JsonSerializer** and **JsonDeserializer**.

```
@JsonComponent
public class PointSerializer extends JsonSerializer<com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point>{

    @Override
 public void serialize(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
     gen.writeStartObject();
     gen.writeNumberField("lat", value.getY());
     gen.writeNumberField("lon", value.getX());
     gen.writeEndObject();
 }
}
```