# Configuring spring boot with hibernate spatial

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, hibernate-spatial

Hello I have problem with booting up my spring app. Hibernate produce following error HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found. 
My POM looks like this :

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.M5</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1204-jdbc42</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>hr.softwarecity.osijek.App</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat>tomacat8</tomcat>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And my application.properties looks like this:
server.port: 8080

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/proba

spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

spring.datasource.username: //username

spring.datasource.password: //pw
```

and on boot up I get following stacktrace:

```
2015-10-20 19:43:00.343  WARN 6048 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.StandardConverters
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/config/spi/StandardConverters
    at org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.java:46) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.java:30) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/config/spi/StandardConverters
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:980) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at hr.softwarecity.osijek.App.main(App.java:14) [classes/:na]
2015-10-20 19:43:00.343  INFO 6048 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2015-10-20 19:43:00.359  INFO 6048 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/organiziraj/osc/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.1.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.1.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.1/jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.1/jackson-annotations-2.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.1/jackson-core-2.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1204-jdbc42/postgresql-9.4-1204-jdbc42.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-spatial/5.0.2.Final/hibernate-spatial-5.0.2.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/geolatte/geolatte-geom/1.0/geolatte-geom-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.13/jts-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/apfloat/apfloat/1.8.2/apfloat-1.8.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.6/aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.6/aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.0.M5/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.0.M5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.26/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.26/tomcat-juli-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.0.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Leon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar]
2015-10-20 19:43:00.359 ERROR 6048 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.StandardConverters
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/config/spi/StandardConverters
    at org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.java:46) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.initiateService(SpatialDialectFactoryInitiator.java:30) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.0.2.Final.jar:5.0.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/config/spi/StandardConverters
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstraException in thread "main" ctAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:980) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at hr.softwarecity.osijek.App.main(App.java:14) [classesorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/config/spi/StandardConverters
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    /:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at
```

Comment: Weird, this class is in `hibernate-core` that `hibernate-spatial` brings. Did you clean your server, rebuilt, etc.?

Comment: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final} is the hibernate version of this project. On hibernate spatial page stands that Hibernate Spatial version 4.3 is compatible with Hibernate 4.3.x onl. In my pom i have hibernate spatial version 5.0.1 i tried to downgrade it but on maven only available hibspatial is 5.0.X version...

Answer (score 3):

Like i said in the comment my hibernate version wasn't compatible with hibernate-spatial 5.0.X. So i downgraded hibernate spatial to

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
 <repositories>
      <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

[Map a PostGIS geometry point field with Hibernate on Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624940/map-a-postgis-geometry-point-field-with-hibernate-on-spring-boot)  and use this question and response to set up my JPArepositories.